# Google Plus SDK - Getting "Your browser is not supported anymore." iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, google-plus, mobile-safari, google-plus-signin

I want to use Google Plus sharing for my iOS application.
I previously used native sharing, but [this website from Google+](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/) says that it's deprecated and suggests using [basic sharing](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/basic-share).

Problem is, after I've done that, when I open the link, it (obviously) opens in Safari and I'm getting the error on the error:
"This browser is no longer supported" and something asks to update a browser.

I'm using iPhone 7 Plus on iOS 10. I've also tried simulator for iOS 9.

Any advice?

Comment: Hey, i am gettig this same error, did you find solution for the same.

Comment: @WasifSaood This won't help you, but since the SDK is not supported by Google (last update on December 2014 I believe), we decided to exclude it from our app. So I'm not using Google Plus SDK for iOS anymore.. :/

Comment: Hey, we made it correct now, we implemented sharing on Google+ using basic sharong feature, as in safari if user is not logged in then it gives such error, so best way to do is make user login first and from next time check current user, it should not go every time for login next time it should open share dialogue on safari.